# SharePoint Lookup column with Handelbars

Tags: lookup-column, content-query-web-part, html

I am using Content query to get information from SharePoint list and display them via Handelbars template on a SharePoint SPFX Page.

Everything works fine except for column defined with lookup.
For lookup-columns I get and id back and not the value.
Example :

- I have column "Process Code" based on lookup on a list Processes (column Code & name). The field used in the lookup is "Name" but with the content query I get an id and not the name value.
- Other example : I have a column "Owner" from type people link to a group of people. In content query, I also get an id and not the information related to the people.

Can some one help me or give me a direction to look at?

Comment: Can you share code which you are using to get list items from SharePoint and also handlerbar template which you are using?

Comment: Thanks for feedback
I have the impression that the issue is not linked to the template but more on the query in the "Content Query" that returns only internal id and not the name.

Comment: @kalpesch Vaghela - Here the "content query" - I add a word document with different printscreens

Comment: I think you missed to provide me link?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/b/s!ApxmPMWaUNGYyl4Svs-qz8aEpAF9?e=SefsHK